# Assigning a unique id to the first instance of a string in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a set of data that has multiple rows with the same `unique_string_identifier`. I want to assign a new unique ID from a sequence to the first instance of a row with that `unique_string_identifier` then give any following rows with the same `unique_string_identifier` the ID times -1. I've tried it three different ways, but I always get

ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

Here are my attempts:

```
UPDATE my_table
    set my_id =
        CASE    WHEN LAG(unique_string_identifier, 1, '-') OVER (order by unique_string_identifier) <> unique_string_identifier THEN my_id_seq.nextval
                ELSE LAG(-1 * my_id, 1, '-') OVER (order by unique_string_identifier) END CASE
    where import_run_id = a_run_id;
```

I've also tried this:

```
    UPDATE my_table
    set my_id = my_id_seq.nextval
    where row_number() over (partition by unique_string_identifier order by line_id) = 1;
//another update statement to make the rows with null ID's equal to the negative id joined on unique_string_identifier
```

And this:

```
UPDATE my_Table
    set my_id =
        decode(unique_string_identifier, LAG(unique_string_identifier, 1, '-') OVER (order by unique_string_identifier), LAG( my_id, 1, '-') OVER (order by unique_string_identifier), my_id_seq.nextval)
    where import_run_id = a_run_id;
```

How can I make this work?

EDIT: Also for my own enrichment, if anyone can explain why these 3 statements (which all seem pretty different to me) end up getting the exact same ORA error, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What does "first instance of a row" mean in this unordered SQL table?

Comment: One instance might be a better way to put it, but out of a set of rows with the same string identifier I want only one row to have the positive ID.

Comment: Does it matter *which* row?

Comment: No, just as long as it's only one per string identifier.

Comment: For the question about the error, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm: "Analytic functions compute an aggregate value based on a group of rows. They differ from aggregate functions in that they return multiple rows for each group. The group of rows is called a window and is defined by the analytic_clause." You've got analytic functions in each statement (LAG, ROW_NUMBER)

Comment: A simple approach here might be to simply do this in 2 update statements. First, update a single instance of each string with an ID; then, update the other instances with a lookup. Performance would not be great, though, esp. if there's no index on the string column. Another approach is to use a MERGE - if I get it working I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't work out a simple MERGE or set of UPDATEs, but here is a potential solution that might work fine, tested on Oracle 11g, using PL/SQL:

Test scenario:

```
create table my_table (unique_string varchar2(100));

insert into my_table values ('aaa');
insert into my_table values ('aaa');
insert into my_table values ('aaa');
insert into my_table values ('bbb');
insert into my_table values ('bbb');
insert into my_table values ('ccc');

alter table my_table add (id number);

create sequence my_seq;
```

Here's the PL/SQL to do the update:

```
declare
cursor c is
  select unique_string
        ,row_number()
         over (partition by unique_string order by 1)
         as rn
  from my_table
  order by unique_string
  for update of id;
r c%rowtype;
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into r;
    exit when c%notfound;
    if r.rn = 1 then
      update my_table
      set id = my_seq.nextval
      where current of c;
    else
      update my_table
      set id = my_seq.currval * -1
      where current of c;
    end if;
  end loop;
  close c;
end;
/
```

Results from my test (note that the sequence had advanced a little by this stage):

```
select * from my_table;

UNIQUE_STRING  ID
=============  ==
aaa             7
aaa            -7
aaa            -7
bbb             8
bbb            -8
ccc             9
```

P.S. I've been a bit sneaky and taken advantage of Oracle's tendency to return ROW_NUMBER in the order that the rows are returned; to be more robust and correct, I'd put the query in a subquery and `ORDER BY unique_string, rn`.